# Get model property from Ember view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

I have my Route setup with models from FireBase:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return EmberFire.Array.create({
      ref: new Firebase("https://some-database.firebaseio.com/shape")
    });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

In the template I'm display each array object within a view with #each:

```
{#each controller}}
    {{#view App.ColorView}}
    <div>{{color}}</div>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

And in the view I like a click action to delete the particular color:

```
App.ColorView = Ember.View.extend({
      click: function() {
          var theColor = this.get('content');
        console.log(theColor);
      }
  });
```

Currently a list of colors show up int he view but I'm getting "undefined" when I try to access the model property belongs to this object. Are there additional setup that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass using `contentBinding`

```
{#each controller}}
    {{#view App.ColorView contentBinding=this}}
    <div>{{color}}</div>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Once I bind the content and call 
var item = this.getProperties('color');
        console.log(item);

I received Object {color: undefined}.

Comment: you need to use `this.get('content.color')` inside of your view. I think that this.getProperties('color') is trying to retrieve from your view, but you view doesn't have colours, just the content.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks alot! It appears that when I set a new color my view changes but model doesn't persist, do you know what is the proper way to update a property?

Comment: Probably if you use `contentBinding=color` when the color change the view will be updated.